# Jquery Mobile Fixed Header mis-alignment in PhoneGap

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am working on a phonegap app that uses jquery mobile.  I am currently debugging in the IOS simulator.

I am using the persistent fixed header toolbar from JQuery Mobile.

On my login page I have a form for entering the username and password.

After the username and password are entered, and the user hits "go" the form starts submitting, the keyboard is hidden, and then the top header toolbar is pushed down the page.

Does anyone have a workaround for this issue so the header stays at the top?

Screen shots below of the initial view and the view after form submission with the pushed down header.

Thanks!

-TWilly

[image]

[image]

Comment: I also facing same problem. Help me if you got the answer

Comment: What version of phonegap are you using?  There has been a lot of improvements related to keyboard opening/closing and re-sizing the webview.  You should try setting the keyboardShrinksWebView to true.

Comment: i am using cordova.js